# How to design planar toroidal inductors using Altium designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, planar-inductor

Prior to this, I did spiral inductors which was relatively easy. But I am now stuck in designing toroidal inductors.

[image: Toroidal inductor (top & bottom layer]

I know the distance between each turns but having trouble placing them in circular fashion. Any ideas on how to place them in such manner?

[image: planar pcb toroidal inductor]

Comment: https://forum.live.altium.com/ -- Ask here for better answers.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For spiral or circular placement, In my opinion, The best way is to create a **Polar Grid**.

This can be found in the Grid Manager. The same method can be used in footprint design and component placement.

[Link to Altium Help Page on Polar Grid](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/PCB_Dlg-GridEditorForm_Panel_Main_Panel_Grid_PolarGridFrame((Polar+Grid+Editor))_AD)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This method was really helpful. I had some trouble selecting the points while placing the petals, but once I figured it out, it worked.